# PHP split string City State Zip to array

Tags: php, string

I have one string holding the city state and zip codes. Besides the random commas, spaces and periods. The only constant would be the last GA, SC, FL state abbreviations and zip code numbers at the end. Is there a preg match that would work with this?

Atlanta, GA 30303-1422
Atlanta,GA 30302
Atlanta, GA. 30301
Atlanta GA 30304
Atlanta,GA.30302
Atlanta GA, 30301
AtlantaGA 30301
Tampa Fl33601
Warner Robins, GA 31005
TAMPA, FL33601
Fleming Island, FL 32003

Output to array
0 = Atlanta
1 = GA
2 = 30301

Comment: Remove them and split on space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a perfect solution, but seems to split and filter. 1. Grab all the numbers 2. reverse the string and get the first two characters A-Z, then the rest of string 3. reverse string back to correct order and filter.

```
function split_csz($csz){ //CSZ City State Zip
    //Zip
    $zip = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $csz);
    echo("The extracted numbers zip are: $zip");
    $csz = strrev("$csz");
    //echo("The string is reversed: $csz");
    //State
    preg_match('/([A-Za-z]{2})(.+)/', $csz, $city_state);
    $state = strrev("$city_state[1]");
    echo("The extracted state is: $state");
    //City
    $city = strrev("$city_state[2]");
    $city = preg_replace('/[.,]/', '', $city);
    echo("The extracted city is: $city");

    $csz_returned = array($city,$state,$zip);
return $csz_returned;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet here (since the number of staates is pretty limited) is to use `preg_split()`:

```
preg_split('/(GA|FL|SC)/i', $address, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

That will return an array containing the split out values before, at, and after the list of states. This has a few issues still like `Fleming Island` having its `Fl` split from `eming Island` as well as keeping around all of the punctuation. You could get a little deeper in your split criteria and perhaps `preg_match()` your way to cleaner output.

That being said I feel like with a sufficiently large list of values you will be chasing edge cases until the heat death of the universe.

As a working example from your small list of addresses:

```
$address_array[]='Atlanta, GA 30303-1422';
$address_array[]='Atlanta,GA 30302';
$address_array[]='Atlanta, GA. 30301';
$address_array[]='Atlanta GA 30304';
$address_array[]='Atlanta,GA.30302';
$address_array[]='Atlanta GA, 30301';
$address_array[]='AtlantaGA 30301';
$address_array[]='Tampa Fl33601';
$address_array[]='Warner Robins, GA 31005';
$address_array[]='TAMPA, FL33601';
$address_array[]='Fleming Island, FL 32003';

foreach ( $address_array as $address) {
    $address_parts = preg_split('/(^.*)(GA|FL|SC)/i', $address, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    foreach( $address_parts as $address_part ){
        echo preg_match('/([a-zA-Z 0-9]+)/', $address_part, $out) ? trim($out[0])."\n" : '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I have been over it left and right over the past few days. I finally decided to reverse the string. It isn't perfect, but this lead to finding a solution that will semi-work.